# distinctive vs distinct

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> The distinctive long neck of a giraffe, for example, developed as individuals that happened to have longer necks had an advantage in feeding on the leaves of tall trees.

> The distinct long neck of a giraffe, for example, developed as individuals that happened to have longer necks had an advantage in feeding on the leaves of tall trees.

What is more appropriate word for the sentence above?

Comment: "Distinctive" is more suitable as **It suggests that those characteristics are not only different but also noteworthy or remarkable.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [5 most common nouns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The%20distinct%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in a sentence starting with *The distinct...* are ***advantage, feature, difference, features, nature.***

The [5 most common nouns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The%20distinctive%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in a sentence starting with *The distinctive...* are ***feature, features, character, characteristics, characteristic.***

It's unrealistic to suppose that the two usages are somehow referring to *different "types" of **features***, so I suggest the two adjectival forms are to a considerable extent interchangeable.

---

But note that ***distinct*** tends to mean ***clearly discernible*** (sharply defined, not out of focus), whereas ***distinctive*** is more often used to mean ***striking, noteworthy*** and/or ***clearly distinguishable*** (easily identified as "different" to other things of the same general class).

So Hitler's ***distinctive toothbrush mustache***, for example, is thus referenced because it stands out from other mustache styles, but a ***distinct echo*** is one that can be heard clearly (we're not normally comparing it to *other* echoes! :)

---

For OP's *exact* context, there's no doubt that the most common adjective is ***distinctive** long neck* (easily distinguishable from the necks of other animals), but there are a number of written references to a [***distinct long neck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22distinct%20long%20neck%22) in Google Books, so I'd say that's a "valid, but less common stylistic choice".

There are also a number of written references to a [***distinctly long neck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22distinctly%20long%20neck%22) *(**unquestionably** long)*, which in some contexts is a perfectly reasonable stylistic choice.

Answer (score 3):

Merriam-Webster defines **[distinctive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinctive)** as:

> 1a: marking as separate or different : serving to distinguish
> *the **distinctive** flight of the crane* 
> 1b: having or giving an uncommon and appealing quality : having or giving style or distinction
> *a **distinctive** table setting* 
> *a writer with a **distinctive** prose style*

For **[distinct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinct)** the same dictionary gives this as its first two definitions:

> 1: distinguishable to the eye or mind as being discrete or not the same: SEPARATE
> *a **distinct** cultural group*
> *teaching as **distinct** from research*
> 2: presenting a clear unmistakable impression
> *a neat **distinct** handwriting*

They are obviously related words but not the same. It's clearer if you compare the opposite meaning of the two words. **Distinctive** contrasts with ordinary or uninteresting; **distinct** contrasts with vague or unidentifiable.

- *My son has very **distinctive** handwriting* (Meaning, he's the only
  person I know who has that style of writing.)
- *My son has very **distinct** handwriting* (Meaning, he writes so clearly
  that even with my poor eyesight I have no trouble reading it.)

So you probably mean *distinctive*.

Answer (score 2):

*Distinctive* means tending to distinguish, whereas *distinct* means either separate or particular. So in your example, if one wishes to say “what sets them apart,” the better choice is *distinctive*.